# Clamav not accepting parameters

Tags: command-line, malware, antivirus, clamav

I'm trying to run clamAV, and I was getting warnings about maxfile size reached.So now, I am trying to increase the limits on the max filesize, and max scan size, but I get errors, about not being able to parse the command-line options. I have read the manpage, and I can't figure out how to use these options. Can someone assist? What am I doing wrong?

```
~$ sudo clamscan -r --max-filesize=1G --max-scansize=1G -l ClamScanLog -i /
ERROR: Incorrect argument format for option --max-filesize
ERROR: Can't parse command line options
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--max-filesize argument accepts only "k" and "m" modifiers, not "g".

Try this instead:

```
sudo clamscan -r --max-filesize=1024M --max-scansize=1024M -l ClamScanLog -i /
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man clamscan`:

```
--max-filesize=#n
Extract and scan at most #n kilobytes from each archive. You may pass the value in megabytes in format xM or xm, where x is a number. This option protects your system against DoS attacks (default: 25 MB, max: <4 GB)
--max-scansize=#n
Extract and scan at most #n kilobytes from each scanned file. You may pass the value in megabytes in format xM or xm, where x is a number. This option protects your system against DoS attacks (default: 100 MB, max: <4 GB)
```

The `max-filesize`and `max-scansize` options for `clamscan` accept a number, interpreted as KB, or a number followed by M, interpreted as MB. It does not know GB, so you will have to write that as 1024M.